# change the colorbar width

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

[image]

I have created this, as you can see the colorbar is very thin, is there anyway of increasing the width of the colorbar without increasing the height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get hold of the axes of the colorbar.
Assuming you hold a reference to the colorbar in `cbar` you get to the axes via `cbar.ax`.

You can control the ratio of the **height / width** with `ax.set_aspect(number)`. This will rescale the axes to match this ratio, but which way the rescaling is performed is not fully understood by me:

I might increase / decrease this number gradually in small steps and the axes would shrink / extent in one dimension to match the ratio accordingly. But at some point the behavior changes and further increase / decrease yields extension / shrinkage in the other dimension.

The documentation for [axes.set_aspect](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=aspect#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) says:

> a circle will be stretched such that the height is num times the
>   width. aspect=1 is the same as aspect=’equal’

If you want to avoid this hassle completely you set `ax.set_aspect('auto')` and afterwards set the exact position of the axes explicitly with

```
ax.set_position((left, bottom, width, height))
```

The units are relative to the figure canvas and stretch from `0` to `1` with `0,0` being the bottom left corner of the canvas.

Example: `set_position((0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6))` will position the axes bottom left edge at `(0.1, 0.2)` and the top right edge at `(0.1 + 0.4, 0.2 + 0.6)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired width of the colorbar using a combination of `fraction` and `aspect` parameters: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers; the value of your answer would be greatly improved by providing a [properly-formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) example. See [answer] for more information.